# how to handle System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, .net, exception, machine-learning, indexoutofrangeexception

I am trying to debug the code and run into this System.IndexOutOfRangeException. Can somebody help me how to resolve it. Please look in the image where exception occurs. It reads the first line of "Line Array" successfully but when it comes to second line exception occurs. Exception occurs when i =1 and j= 0.
Here is :

[(Image of Exception)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YBCk.png)[(Image of Line Array)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnqEv.png)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace Handwriting.SVMs
{
    static class Features
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///   Extracts an image from a text containing the 
        ///   image representation as binary 0s and 1s.
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        public static Bitmap Extract(string text)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(32, 32, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
            string[] lines = text.Split(new String[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
                {       
                    if (lines[i][j] == '0')
                        bitmap.SetPixel(j, i, Color.White);
                    else bitmap.SetPixel(j, i, Color.Black);
                }
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   Extracts a feature vector representation from
        ///   an image, "flattening" a binary image into an
        ///   array of 0s and 1s.
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        public static double[] Extract(Bitmap bmp)
        {
            double[] features = new double[32 * 32];
            for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
                    features[i * 32 + j] = (bmp.GetPixel(j, i).R == 255) ? 0 : 1;

            return features;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   Converts a feature vector containing 0s and 1s
        ///   representing each pixel in the image back into
        ///   an image.
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        public static Bitmap Export(double[] features)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(32, 32, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);

            for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
                {
                    double v = features[i * 32 + j];
                    v = 255 - Math.Max(0, Math.Min(255, Math.Abs(v) * 255));
                    bitmap.SetPixel(j, i, Color.FromArgb((int)v, (int)v, (int)v));
                }

            return bitmap;
        }

        public static double[] Preprocess(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            double[] features = new double[64];

            for (int m = 0; m < 8; m++)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < 8; n++)
                {
                    int c = m * 8 + n;
                    for (int i = m * 4; i < m * 4 + 4; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = n * 4; j < n * 4 + 4; j++)
                        {
                            Color pixel = bitmap.GetPixel(j, i);
                            if (pixel.R == 0x00) // white
                                features[c] += 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return features;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: seems lines[1] = string.Empty

Comment: No, because of `.RemoveEmptyEntries`.  I think `lines.Length == 1`

Comment: I agree with @HenkHolterman. This could happen for example if in the `text` string there is a ------- `\r\n \r\n` (note the blank space)

Comment: If you look at the attached image, there is lines[0] containing the whole picture, line 1 does not exist.

Comment: just make sure you clean/rebuild you solution and debug it carefully. You'll figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace

```
string[] lines = text.Split(new String[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

by

```
string[] lines = text.Split(Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Also, you must be sure that `text` contains at least 32 non-empty lines with 32 characters in every line. If the changing of `Split` doesn't help you then it is problem in `text` variable.

From your description it seems that there is no `lines[1];`

All your lines are placed in `lines[0];` - you can see it in the second image

Comment: It probably has to do with the Split but this is just a cosmetic change.

Comment: It didn't help. says invalid argument.

Comment: @EhsanUlHaq, could I get the value of text variable from you? In your second picture lines[0] has many lines, maybe problem is there? lines[0] should be first line in image, lines[1] - second ...

Comment: I have attached the image of text, you can have a look